# saving state for a Java class that uses a recursive method

Tags: java

I have a Jave class that calculates all possible combination for a given array of elements and to do this it uses a recursive method.
It work fine but when the number of input elements raises I found out of memory problem.
What I'd like to do is calculate combinations in chuncks of a given size.
My problem is that I don't know how save and than restore the state for the recursive method,
specially when it the calling depth is high.
Beolw is the code.
Thanks a lot.

```
package uty;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ESCalcCombination {

    int iMax = 0;
    boolean bEnd = false;
    int iLenInp;
    ArrayList<Integer[]> resultList;

    public ESCalcCombination(int[] inElements, int inMaxElem, int inMaxElemLen) {
        if (inMaxElem > 0) {
            iMax = inMaxElem;
        } else {
            iMax = new Double(Math.pow(2d, new Integer(inElements.length).doubleValue())).intValue();
        }
        resultList = new ArrayList(iMax);
        iLenInp = inElements.length;
        for (int i = 1; i <= iLenInp; i++) {
            if (inMaxElemLen > 0) {
                if (i > inMaxElemLen) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < iLenInp; j++) {
                if ((iLenInp - j) < i) {
                    break;
                }
                addNextElement(inElements, j, i, null);
                if (bEnd) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (bEnd) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void addNextElement(int[] inElements, int inCurIndex, int inLimitLen, ArrayList<Integer> inCurrentCombination) {
        if (inCurrentCombination != null
                && (inCurrentCombination.size() + (iLenInp - inCurIndex)) < inLimitLen) {
            return;
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> alCombinationLoc = new ArrayList();
        if (inCurrentCombination != null) {
            alCombinationLoc.addAll(inCurrentCombination);
        }
        alCombinationLoc.add(inElements[inCurIndex]);
        if (alCombinationLoc.size() == inLimitLen) {
            Integer[] arComb = new Integer[alCombinationLoc.size()];
            arComb = alCombinationLoc.toArray(arComb);
            resultList.add(arComb);
            alCombinationLoc.clear();
            alCombinationLoc = null;
            if (resultList.size() == iMax) {
                bEnd = true;
            }
            return;
        }
        for (int i = ++inCurIndex; i < iLenInp; i++) {
            addNextElement(inElements, i, inLimitLen, alCombinationLoc);
            if (bEnd) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        ESUty.closeAL(resultList);
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer[]> getCombinations() {
        return resultList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ESCalcCombination ESCaCo = new ESCalcCombination(new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 0, 15);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\test\\conbinations.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < ESCaCo.getCombinations().size(); i++) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int j = 0; j < ESCaCo.getCombinations().get(i).length; j++) {
                    sb.append(ESCaCo.getCombinations().get(i)[j]);
                }
                System.out.println("elemento " + i + " = " + sb.toString());
                fos.write((sb.toString() + System.getProperty("line.separator")).getBytes());

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("errore " + ex);
        } finally {
            ESUty.closeFileOutputStream(fos);

        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to find nCr here?

Comment: Put method in class. Store iterator position in instance variable. Set value in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

With recursion, part of the data is on stack, and stack cannot be saved that easily. If such functionality is required, rewrite everything using while loop together with the [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) or [ArrayDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) data structure instead. This allows to save and restore the state without problems.

Comment: `java.util.Stack` is one of the old JDK 1.0 data structures. It's better to use the newer and faster `java.util.ArrayDeque`.